# How can I add an active selector

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I need to add an active selector so that when any of these is clicked on the active class will be bold. Also active selector needs to remain even after page is refreshed.

Manuals
International
Tracking
Contacts
Security
Registration
Policy
Troubleshooting
Promotions
Shipping
Terms
Claim

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="container-inner">
    {{breadcrumbs}}
    <div class="search-box search-box_page">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 25 26">
    <path d="M20,18.9c1.6-2.1,2.4-4.6,2.4-7.2c0-6.4-5-11.7-11.2-11.7C5,0,0,5.3,0,11.7s5,11.7,11.2,11.7
          c2.5,0,5-0.9,6.9-2.5l4.6,4.8c0.3,0.3,0.6,0.4,0.9,0.4c0.3,0,0.7-0.1,0.9-0.4c0.5-0.6,0.5-1.4,0-2L20,18.9z M20,12
          c0,4.9-3.8,9-8.5,9s-9.1-4.1-9.1-9s4.4-9.5,9.1-9.5S20,7,20,12z"/>
  </svg>
  {{search instant=true placeholder=settings.search_placeholder}}
</div>

        <div class="section group">
    <div class="left-nav col span_1_of_2_">
    <h2 class="leftnav-title">Support</h2>
        <ul style="color:#333;">
      <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test1.com"><li>Manuals</li></a>
      <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test2.com"><li>International</li></a>
      <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test3.com"><li>Tracking</li></a>
      <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test4.com"><li>Contacts</li></a>
      <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test5.com"><li>Security</li></a>
      <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test6.com"><li>Registration</li></a>
      <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test7.com"><li>Policy</li></a>
      <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test8.com"><li>Troubleshooting</li></a>
      <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test9.com"><li>Promotions</li></a>
      <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test10.com"><li>Shipping</li></a>
      <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test11.com"><li>Terms</li></a>
      <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test12.com"><li>Claim</li></a>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_2">
        <div style="" class="category-tree" id="section">
      <section class="category-tree__item">
        <h2 class="category-tree__title">{{section.name}}</h2>
      <div class="accordion-wrapper">
  {{#each section.articles}}
  <ul data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{id}}" class="article-list article-list_page">
    <li class="article-list__item">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="cursor: default;" class="art-title">{{title}}</a>
      <article style="font-weight:100;" id="{{id}}" class="article-body collapse art-body">
      {{body}}
      </article>
    </li>
  </ul>
  {{/each}}
</div>
    </div>
</div>


      </section>
      {{pagination}}
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you're looking for is the [builtin `localStorage` JavaScript API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Links already have an active selector after being clicked on...

Comment: Along with that, you'll probably want to [`addEventListener`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the elements you want to add classes to when clicked. And using localStorage, when the page loads add back in the ones that were clicked.

Comment: @chbchb55 How can I do this? sorry new to this

Comment: @DevAnd when you click on a link, did you want to go to that link or stay on the current page?

Comment: @leonsegal I want to visit the new page but the new page is the same thing just that the content changes but the left-nav remains the same on the page.

Comment: @leonsegal it's basically something similar to this. https://www.oneplus.com/support/faq#85000010

Comment: Nothing has worked on Zendesk. I see it working on jsfiddle but not zendesk. @leonsegal

Comment: @DevAnd Are you getting any error messages in the console?

Answer (score 0):

As I said above in the comments, what we're doing here is we're using `localStorage.setItem` to save the active links and `localStorage.getItem` to retrieve they're values. Then `.addEventListner` and `.removeEventListener` to make sure that once a link is clicked it adds the class `active` to our link and `localStorage`.

```
function makeActive(event) {
  event.target.classList.add('active')
  event.target.removeEventListener('click', makeActive)
  localStorage.setItem(event.target.href, 'active')
}


document
  .querySelectorAll('a.link-leftbar:not(.active)')
  .forEach(link => link.addEventListner('click', makeActive))

function setActiveLinksClass() {
  document
    .querySelectorAll('a.link-leftbar')
    .forEach(link => {
      if (localStorage.getItem(link.href) !== null)
        link.classList.add('active')
    })

document
  .addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setActiveLinksClass)
```

Please check out the links in the comments if you don't understand what this stuff means.

Answer (score 0):

People have already answer for the active link problem of yours.
So I think I should just focus on the second one
And the first thing come up to me is THAT YOU SHOULD NOT SAVE THINGS IN LOCAL STORAGE
Except some variables that really worldwide using in your entire application
 
My suggestion is that you using url params.

```
https://exampleurl.com?active[]=manual&active=tracking&...
```

Then using

```
$.parseParams( url.split('?')[1] || '' );//result would be {active: ['manual', 'tracking',... ]}
```

**What are the benefits out of this?**
Firstly, you will be able to refresh your page and things still there as you wish.
Secondly, user go to `https://exampleurl.com` and all the active filter has gone.Which they don't have to manually remove the active link themselves.
Third, you won't have to handle the local storage which will get more and more complicated when you app scale and messing with local storage is not a good idea.
Finally, user can actually access your page with `https://exampleurl.com?active[]=manual` and they still be able to see the "Manuals" active link with correct url above.

```
<ul>
  <a class="link-leftbar" id="manual" onClick="onClickLink('manual')" href="www.test1.com"><li>Manuals</li></a>
  <a class="link-leftbar" id="inter" onClick="onClickLink('inter')" href="www.test2.com"><li>International</li></a>
  <a class="link-leftbar" id="tracking" href="www.test3.com"><li>Tracking</li></a>
  ......
</ul>


<script>
  var selectedIds = [];
  function onClickLink(id) {
    var selectedItem = document.querySelector('#' + id);
    var isSelected = selectedItem.classList.contain('active');
    if (!isSelected) {
      this.selectedItem.classList.add('active');
    } else {
      this.selectedItem.classList.remove('active');
    }

    newStateUrl(id);//Only push newState to your url, later refresh still remain with all selectedIds.
  }

  function newStateUrl(id) {
    var idx = selectedIds.indexOf(id);
    if (idx === -1) {
      selectedIds.push(id);
    } else {
      selectedIds = selectedIds.splice(idx, 1);
    }

    var newUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
    var params = '?' + $.param({active: selectedIds});//?active%5b%5D=manual&active%B%5D=tracking
    newUrl += params;
    window.history.pushState({path: newUrl},'', newUrl);
  }

  //This is for when you access the page for the first time
 $(document).ready(function() {
   selectedIds = [];
   var url = window.location.href;
   // You can look up the parseParams from this link
   // https://gist.github.com/kares/956897
   params = $.parseParams( url.split('?')[1] || '' );
   params.forEach(function(param)b{
     onClinkLink(id);
   });
 });

</script>
```

Comment: Hi can you help me inputting the info you left out above like urls and id's? I am little lost there.

Comment: the urls you can find in the question above.
And the id's is just the way I make the '<a></a>' tags become unique, you can set the rest of the urls following the id's that you want.

Answer (score 0):

So here is how you could do it without using local storage. I think using local storage isn't that bad, but the url params way seems to make more sense in this case.

I took the previous example posted here and simplified it a bit, also I don't think it was selecting an active record (i.e. only one):

CSS

```
<style>
        .active {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class="link-leftbar" id="manuals" onClick="setActiveLink('manuals')" href="">
            Manuals
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="link-leftbar" id="international" onClick="setActiveLink('international')" href="">
            International
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="link-leftbar" id="tracking" onClick="setActiveLink('tracking')" href="">
            Tracking
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript/jQuery

```
<script>
    const setActiveLink = linkName => {
        const
            baseUrl = window.location.href.split('?')[0],
            newUrl = baseUrl + '?' + $.param({active: linkName});

        $('.link-leftbar')
            .removeClass('active')
            .filter('#' + linkName)
            .addClass('active');

        window.history.pushState({path: newUrl}, '', newUrl);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        const params = $.parseParams(window.location.href.split('?')[1] || '');

        setActiveLink(params.active);
    });
</script>
```

You will have to ensure that the sidebar is on the page it navigates to and also that the script dealing with active classes is on that page.

You will have to pull in the parseParams library from [here](https://gist.github.com/kares/956897) too.

Comment: Is there anything I have to insert into that script? @leonsegal

Comment: or will that script work if i paste it as is?

Comment: @DevAnd not sure it will - it's rarely the case you can do that. Most things like this are prescriptive and usually need finessing.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

Html

```
<ul>
    <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test1.com"><li>Manuals</li></a>
    <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test2.com"><li>International</li></a>
    <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test3.com"><li>Tracking</li></a>
    <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test4.com"><li>Contacts</li></a>
    <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test5.com"><li>Security</li></a>
    <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test6.com"><li>Registration</li></a>
    <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test7.com"><li>Policy</li></a>
    <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test8.com"><li>Troubleshooting</li></a>
    <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test9.com"><li>Promotions</li></a>
    <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test10.com"><li>Shipping</li></a>
    <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test11.com"><li>Terms</li></a>
    <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test12.com"><li>Claim</li></a>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.active {
    font-weight: bold
}
```

JavaScript

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".link-leftbar");
let activeUrl = localStorage.getItem('activeLink'), activeLink;

buttons.forEach(button => {
    if (activeUrl === button.href) {
        button.classList.add('active')
    }
});

buttons.forEach(currentButton => currentButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        buttons.forEach(button => button.classList.remove('active'));

        currentButton.classList.add('active');

        activeLink = document.querySelector('.active');
        localStorage.setItem('activeLink', activeLink);
    }
));
```

It's a bit brittle (might break if the addresses changed for example), but it sets the active class on click and remembers the result after page refresh

How it works is, it sets the links as an html collection, which you can loop through using forEach.

The activeUrl is then also set (undefined if not already set).

It then loops through the links and if the activeUrl address is the same as the given link, it will add the active class to that link.

Then it loops over the links again to set an eventhandler for each one.

In the eventhandler, when a link is clicked, it removes any existing active class on any link, then adds the active class to that link.

Finally the eventhandler stores that link address as the activeUrl, ready for checking when the page reloads.

Here is it working: https://jsfiddle.net/q0vgw8yk/

--EDIT--

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.link-leftbar')
        .on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $('.active').removeClass('active');

            $(this).addClass('active');

            localStorage.setItem('activeLink', $(this).text());
        })
        .filter(function () {
            return $(this).text() === localStorage.getItem('activeLink')
        })
        .addClass('active');
});
```

jQuery loops through all links with link-leftbar class, adding an eventhandler to each one, then filtering them all down to the one which matches the locally stored active link, which it then adds an active class to.

Inside the eventhandler, it removes the active class from link which currently has that class, then adds it to the link which was clicked.

When a link is clicked, the [event.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method is used. This stops the link doing what it is supposed to do. If you want it to go to the link, you will have to add that in. You should be able to find what you need to do that fairly easily.

It then stores the active link locally, this time though it uses the html of the link as a ref.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey anyway to turn this javascript into jquery? Sorry so much but just realized Zendesk theming is not allowing Javascript and would work better with Jquery.

Comment: Just added a comment @leonsegal

Comment: @DevAnd My jQuery is a bit rusty, but I can try. Are you sure you can't use vanilla JavaScript though? jQuery *is* JavaScript so you should be able to...

Comment: from reading the docs it says it's best to use Jquery

Comment: Hi so it's sort of working but it's not allowing me to travel to any of the links. The links are sort of disabled. @leonsegal

Comment: No idea why it's doing the same thing still. @leonsegal